# Dependent properties in a class

Tags: c#

Is there a way possible to make one property of a class dependent on other automatically.

i.e:

```
class Number {
  string dec;
  char[] binary;
}
```

Whenever dec is changed the binary must also be changed to the corresponding binary value of the dec variable.

Comment: you can change value of binary inside setter of dec... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Comment: type `propfull` and press TAB button.. property will automatically gets created... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/f7d3wz0k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you everyone,yet I changed the approach itself and got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**INotifyPropertyChanged**  is what you are looking for.

As documented on [official site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) :-

> Notifies clients that a property value has changed.
>
> The INotifyPropertyChanged interface is used to notify clients,
>   typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any dependency, just add a method or property which returns the string casted to byte:

```
class Number {
  string dec;

  byte binary() {
    return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.dec);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a getter

```
class Number {

    string dec { get; set; }

    char [] binary { get { return /*logic that computes binary off of dec*/ } }
}
```